# How to hook into positioning top bar fixed menu?

Tags: menu, zurb-foundation

I have transparent top bar. On header links text is white on blue background. But content has white background. I would like to change top bar text color, when menu is on content area.

Browsed the code but found no solution. Any advise?

Comment: Are you using the straight css version, or scss?

Comment: I'm using strainght css